# Subset CSV files in for loop by date and save file with different name

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I have a list of hydrological gages saved as `lgages` that are saved as a `list`.

```
gages<-read.delim("D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial\\TX Gages List only txt.txt", colClasses = c("Gage_ID" = "character"))

# Set Working Directory
setwd("D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial")

#using txt and defining as Character in order to not lose leading zeros in gage id
lgages<-as.list(gages$Gage_ID)

Code <- "00060"         #daily flow
Stat <- "00003"         #mean
start.date <- "1900-01-01"
end.date <- "2020-12-31" #statistical package requires full years of data, either calendar or water
dat.type <- ".csv"
path_2 <- "D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial\\Yearly_Stats_Red\\"
file_list <- list.files(path_2)
```

An example of the list I am working with is this

```
dput(file_list)
c("07223300.csv", 
"07227000.csv", 
"07227200.csv", 
"07227420.csv", 
"07227448.csv", 
"07227470.csv" 
)
```

I am trying to split the data into the CSV files by `year`.

```
   X   staid val      dates qualcode
1   1 7223300  76 1970-10-01        A
2   2 7223300  90 1970-10-02        A
3   3 7223300  94 1970-10-03        A
4   4 7223300 110 1970-10-04        A
5   5 7223300 124 1970-10-05        A
6   6 7223300 140 1970-10-06        A
7   7 7223300 156 1970-10-07        A
8   8 7223300 135 1970-10-08        A
9   9 7223300 117 1970-10-09        A
10 10 7223300 112 1970-10-10        A
    X   staid val      dates qualcode
1   1 7227000  20 1909-01-01        A
2   2 7227000  20 1909-01-02        A
3   3 7227000  20 1909-01-03        A
4   4 7227000  20 1909-01-04        A
5   5 7227000  20 1909-01-05        A
6   6 7227000  20 1909-01-06        A
7   7 7227000  20 1909-01-07        A
8   8 7227000  20 1909-01-08        A
9   9 7227000  20 1909-01-09        A
10 10 7227000  20 1909-01-10        A
    X   staid val      dates qualcode
1   1 7227200   0 1966-06-17      A R
2   2 7227200   0 1966-06-18      A R
3   3 7227200   0 1966-06-19      A R
4   4 7227200   0 1966-06-20      A R
5   5 7227200   0 1966-06-21      A R
6   6 7227200   0 1966-06-22      A R
7   7 7227200   0 1966-06-23      A R
8   8 7227200   0 1966-06-24      A R
9   9 7227200  71 1966-06-25        A
10 10 7227200 130 1966-06-26        A
    X   staid val      dates qualcode
1   1 7227420   0 2007-10-01      A R
2   2 7227420   0 2007-10-02      A R
3   3 7227420   0 2007-10-03      A R
4   4 7227420   0 2007-10-04      A R
5   5 7227420   0 2007-10-05      A R
6   6 7227420   0 2007-10-06      A R
7   7 7227420   0 2007-10-07      A R
8   8 7227420   0 2007-10-08      A R
9   9 7227420   0 2007-10-09      A R
10 10 7227420   0 2007-10-10      A R
    X   staid val      dates qualcode
1   1 7227448 0.0 1967-10-01      A R
2   2 7227448 0.0 1967-10-02      A R
3   3 7227448 0.0 1967-10-03      A R
4   4 7227448 0.0 1967-10-04      A R
5   5 7227448 0.0 1967-10-05      A R
6   6 7227448 0.0 1967-10-06      A R
7   7 7227448 0.5 1967-10-07        A
8   8 7227448 0.0 1967-10-08      A R
9   9 7227448 0.0 1967-10-09      A R
10 10 7227448 0.0 1967-10-10      A R
    X   staid val      dates qualcode
1   1 7227470 2.5 1968-10-01        A
2   2 7227470 2.5 1968-10-02        A
3   3 7227470 2.5 1968-10-03        A
4   4 7227470 4.0 1968-10-04        A
5   5 7227470 5.0 1968-10-05        A
6   6 7227470 4.0 1968-10-06        A
7   7 7227470 3.5 1968-10-07        A
8   8 7227470 4.0 1968-10-08        A
9   9 7227470 5.0 1968-10-09        A
10 10 7227470 6.0 1968-10-10        A
```

The problem that I am running into is how to do this in a for loop as there are more than 800 gages. I have tried using the code below but I don't seem to be getting any outputs.

```
# Set Working Directory
setwd("D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial\\Subsplit Yearly\\")

for (i in 1:length(lgages)) {
  data_daily <- read.csv(paste(path_2, file_list[i], sep = ""))
  header <- head(data_daily$dates,1)
   
  # Setup split by year
  date_str <-as.character(data_daily$dates)
  date_substr <-(substr(date_str,1,4))
  
  # Split files by year
  out <- split(data_daily, date_substr )
  for (j in names(out))
    new_file<- (paste0(j,":", lgages[i]))
    path_out="D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial\\Subsplit Yearly\\"
    fileName=paste(path_out, new_file, dat.type, sep='')
    write.csv(data_daily,fileName)  
  }
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to be in the format `year:gage.csv` so for example

```
1970:07223300.csv
1971:07223300.csv
1972:07223300.csv
1973:07223300.csv
etc...
```

However, the results that I get in the desired working directory are blank files of type `file` and have the name of years only

```
1970
1971
1972
1973
etc...
```

Comment: So no output *and* no error from attempted code? If no error, please remove `tryCatch` and post its message.

Comment: Your loop does not export each subset but entire data frame with different file names: `write.csv(data_daily, fileName)`.

Comment: @Parfait, how would I be able to make it so that my loop exports my subset. Any help would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to load data from a single gage, subset by each year present at that gage, and save the output. Then move on to the next gage. Is that correct? If so, here is my approach:

```
# Load data from one gage at a time
for(i in 1:length(lgages)) {
  data_daily <- read.csv(paste0(path_2, file_list[i]))
  
  # Save data from each year in that gage, one at at time
  # This will continue for all years in a single gage
  for(j in unique(data_daily$year)){
    new_file <- paste0(j, ":", lgages[i])
    path_out <- "D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial\\Subsplit Yearly\\"
    write.csv(x = data_daily[data_daily$year == j,], file = paste0(path_out, new_file))
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the code, but the output was still not coming out as a csv. This must also be because I don't have a column name for year, which is what I want, but for `dates`. I tried adding a colunm with the subset for year 
`data_daily <-data_daily %>% add_column(Year_separated = date_substr)`.
After, I tried running the second `for` loop for `data_daily$years_separated` but after doing this I get the error `object 'Year_separated' not found `.

Comment: Try `new_file <- paste0(j, ":", lgages[i], ".csv")`

Comment: And check the spelling and capitalization of "year_seperated"